# Set global condtional formatting rules programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to set the background color of every row in the "task" column if the "status" column's row is not blank. This is fairly easy to setup. However setting these rules across numerous columns and sheet 1 to sheet 100 can be very tedious.

Given all sheets have the same columns "task" and "status" it should be possible to set a conditional rule on every sheet. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use script to accomplish the task. As I know, there's no way to make conditional formatting by the script, [here's the issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=162). But you can copy formatting:

1. Make one conditional formatting rule on 'Key sheet'
2. Run the script

Here's the code to add into Script Editor:

```
function loopSheetsCopyFormatting() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // define Key Sheet
  var keySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your's
  // define range with formatting
  var rangeAddress = 'A1:A1000'; // change to your's

  var sampleRange = keySheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
  var column = sampleRange.getColumn();
  var columnEnd = column + sampleRange.getWidth() - 1;
  var row = sampleRange.getRow();
  var rowEnd = row + sampleRange.getHeight() - 1; 

  for (var sheetNum = 0; sheetNum < sheets.length; sheetNum++) {

     var copyToSheet = sheets[sheetNum];
     // copy formatting
     sampleRange.copyFormatToRange(
       copyToSheet, 
       column, 
       columnEnd, 
       row, 
       rowEnd);     
  }

}
```

change lines:

```
var keySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your's
```

and this one:

```
var rangeAddress = 'A1:A1000'; // change to your's
```

And then run script once to copy farmatting.